# AWS SNS - SMS not receive to mobile at some times

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-sns

I enable the cognito MFA with SMS method. When I testing this implementation I realized that sometimes I didn't receive the MFA token to the mobile, but at that time in AWS SNS, Text messaging (SMS) log was at success status. I was trying to send MFA code to Sri Lankan (+94) mobile number. My SNS is active in production mode.

In the Text messaging (SMS) delivery log there are two provider response, one is "Message has been accepted by phone carrier" and other one is "Message has been accepted by phone". When I got the "Message has been accepted by phone carrier", on that time I didn't receive the MFA token to my mobile.

I don't see where the problem is considering. Kindly assist to me.